# What happened to _pgmptr?

Tags: c++, windows, path

I have always used `_pgmptr`, which was a `char*` provided by Windows that gave the exact full path of the executable. However, after recently updating MinGW it seems to be defined to NULL instead. Is there any other way to get the full executable path, with out without its name (like instead of `C:\program.exe` just `C:\` would be okay for what I'm doing)?

I'm fine with a platform-independent way or Windows-specific way, as long as it is reliable.

Comment: You can use `argv[0]` (may need to copy it to a global variable)

Comment: That's the thing, though... argv[0] can potentially be some other value depending on how the program is started from the command line versus the explorer.

Comment: Although it's possible to put something completely different in `argv[0]` when manually calling `exec` or similar), I beleive it works for both explorer started and command line started apps.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: no, if you start a program from the command line `argv[0]` will just be whatever was entered on the command line.  Typically this means just the name of the executable, no path, no extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms683197.aspx) is the API function to retrieve the program path and name.

Comment: Documentation of that function even mentions `_pgmptr`; although I have no idea why it wouldn't be available.

Comment: Yes, from that page you linked "The global variable _pgmptr is automatically initialized to the full path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path name of an executable file." is in the Notes section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tza1y5f7.aspx says it's deprecated.